# sap.m.List Scroll to specific Item

Tags: javascript, list, sapui5

I'm using **sap.m.List** in my SAPUI5 Application. There are 90 Entries, one for each day in the last 3 Month. Looks like this:

[image]

Now I want to scroll to a specific CustomListItem, when a Button is clicked. My View is looking like this:
[image]

The Idea is that I have three Buttons for scrolling directly to an month. For example: Today, last Month, third Month. Clicking the Button directly scrolls to the first entry of that month. I just found sth. like `oList.setSelectedItem(oItem, true);` which has no effect.

Someone has an idea how this can be done?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried something like ```oPage.scrollToElement(oList.getItems()[someIndex], 200);```

Comment: @Lumpenstein i tried it, but no effect.

Comment: Why you dont use a filter? so you can filter on every month you want? its than maybe 1 click more but i think its better

Comment: Hi @Jüngealles Thank you - never used this but seems to be the thing i was looking for. Found this small piece at plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/qiWY5K

I will try it out.

Comment: @Sebi try this https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.ViewSettingsDialog the last one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made few modification and able to achieve you requirement.

**View**

```
<!-- Buttons  --> 
<Button text="Previous Month" press="scrollToPreviousMonth" class="sapUiTinyMarginEnd"/> 
<Button text="Today" press="scrollToCurrentMonth" class="sapUiTinyMarginEnd"/> 
<Button text="Next Month" press="scrollToNextMonth"/>

<!-- List inside scroll Container -->   
<ScrollContainer id="oScrollContainer" height="405px" vertical="true">
    <List id="monthList"
        items="{ 
          path: 'dataModel>/items', 
          sorter: { path: 'group', group: true },
          groupHeaderFactory: '.getGroupHeaderMonth' }" 
          includeItemInSelection="true">
        <CustomListItem type="Active">
            <Toolbar>
                <Label text="{dataModel>title}"/>
                <ToolbarSpacer />
                <Label text="{dataModel>day}"/>
                <core:Icon width="50px" src="sap-icon://edit" />
            </Toolbar>
        </CustomListItem>
    </List> 
</ScrollContainer>
```

**Controller**

```
//Setting the data
setDataToView1: function(sType) {   
    var oData = [
       { "title": "Jan-01", "day": "01-01-2019", "status": "often", "group": "1" },
       { "title": "Jan-02", "day": "02-01-2019", "status": "often", "group": "1" },
       { "title": "Jan-03", "day": "03-01-2019", "status": "often", "group": "1" },
       { "title": "Jan-04", "day": "04-01-2019", "status": "often", "group": "1" },

       { "title": "Feb-01", "day": "01-02-2019", "status": "often", "group": "2" },
       { "title": "Feb-02", "day": "02-02-2019", "status": "often", "group": "2" },
       { "title": "Feb-03", "day": "03-02-2019", "status": "often", "group": "2" },
       { "title": "Feb-04", "day": "04-02-2019", "status": "often", "group": "2" },

       { "title": "Mar-01", "day": "01-03-2019", "status": "often", "group": "3" },
       { "title": "Mar-02", "day": "02-03-2019", "status": "often", "group": "3" },
       { "title": "Mar-03", "day": "03-03-2019", "status": "often", "group": "3" },
       { "title": "Mar-04", "day": "04-03-2019", "status": "often", "group": "3" }                 
    ];
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.setData({ "items" : oData });
    this.getView().setModel(oModel, "dataModel");
},
//setting the group header
getGroupHeaderMonth: function (oGroup) {
    var oMonths = { "1" : "Jan", "2" : "Feb", "3" : "Mar", "4" : "Apr", "5" : "May", "6" : "Jun", "7" : "Jul", "8" : "Aug", "9" : "Sep", "10" : "Oct", "11" : "Nov", "12" : "Dec" };
    var custClass = oMonths[oGroup.key] +"MonthHdr";
    return new sap.m.GroupHeaderListItem({
        title: oMonths[oGroup.key],
        upperCase: false
    }).addStyleClass(custClass);
},
//Navigate to previous month list item
scrollToPreviousMonth: function(){
    this.scrollToItem(".JanMonthHdr");
},
//Navigate to current month list item
scrollToCurrentMonth: function(){
    this.scrollToItem(".FebMonthHdr");
},
//Navigate to next month list item
scrollToNextMonth: function(){
    this.scrollToItem(".MarMonthHdr");
},
//Helper function to scrolling to the corresponding list item
scrollToItem: function(sItem) {
    var oScrollList = this.byId("oScrollContainer"),
        oList = this.byId("monthList"),
        sItemId = jQuery(sItem).attr("id"),
        oItem = sap.ui.getCore().byId(sItemId);

    oList.setSelectedItem(oItem);
    oScrollList.scrollToElement(oItem, 2000);       
},
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to take a look at this code snippet from Plunker. I forked another plunker and twitched the code a little bit. In it you can find a list inside a scroll container which is afterwards used for getting to the desired item by knowing an id property of the list item.

http://plnkr.co/edit/a5JwfkvAZcHq7NDoYG5s?p=preview

```
handleSelectChange: function(oEvent) {
      var sId = oEvent.getParameter("selectedItem").getBindingContext().getObject().id;
      var oList = this.getView().byId("ProductList");
      var aListItems = oList.getItems();
      var oListItem;
      aListItems.forEach(function(element){
        var sListObjectId = element.getBindingContext().getObject().id;
        if(sId === sListObjectId){
          oListItem = element;
        }
      })
      var oScrollContainer = this.getView().byId("oScrollContainer");
      jQuery.sap.delayedCall(0, null, function() {
        oScrollContainer.scrollToElement(oListItem);
        oList.setSelectedItem(oListItem);
      });
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the [ScrollDelegate](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m/methods/sap.m.getScrollDelegate) of your surrounding container (in your case FixFlex I think) and then use it to scroll to the selected item. Short example:

```
oFixFlex.getScrollDelegate().scrollToElement(oItem.getDomRef());
```

Another alternative would be to wrap your List in a [Scrollcontainer](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ScrollContainer) as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. The Page was not scrolling with the "scrollToElement" method.

`oPage.scrollToElement(oList.getItems()[someIndex], 200);`

What the documentation says is that the method works only if the element is rendered on the screen. At the point I called the method in the "PatternMatched" event of the controller, the list elements were still not rendered, therefore the "scrollToElement" method did not work.

The solution is to listen to an event that is fired when the list element rendering is complete and call the scroll method there.

XML

```
 <List
   id"list" updateFinished="onUpdateFinished"
    items="{path}">
    ...
  </List>
```

controller

```
onUpdateFinished() {
  

this.getView().byId('page').scrollToElement(this.getView().byId('list').getItems().[someIndex], 1000);

}
```